# How do I install Dan's Guardian on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

I'm trying to install Dans Guardian on a virtual machine. The instructions ask me to run the ./configure script and then execute the command make install. The configure script runs fine but the make install throws errors.

```
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/webmin/dansguardian-2.10/src'
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -D__CONFFILE='"/usr/local/etc/dansguardian/dansguardian.conf"' -D__LOGLOCATION='"/usr/local/var/log/dansguardian/"' -D__PIDDIR='"/usr/local/var/run"' -D__PROXYUSER='"nobody"' -D__PROXYGROUP='"nobody"' -D__CONFDIR='"/usr/local/etc/dansguardian"'      -g -O2  -MT dansguardian-fancy.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/dansguardian-fancy.Tpo -c -o dansguardian-fancy.o `test -f 'downloadmanagers/fancy.cpp' || echo './'`downloadmanagers/fancy.cpp
downloadmanagers/fancy.cpp: In member function âstd::string fancydm::timestring(int)â:
downloadmanagers/fancy.cpp:507:72: error: âsnprintfâ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [dansguardian-fancy.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/webmin/dansguardian-2.10/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/webmin/dansguardian-2.10'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm running 12.04 LTS server x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dan's Guardian 2.10 (the version you're trying to compile) **is available in the official 12.04 repositories.**

Simply run:

```
sudo apt-get install dansguardian
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running "sudo make install" instead? If you don't have permissions to modify the installation directories the installation may fail.

Comment: Yep I get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add in the file downloadmanagers/fancy.cpp this line:

> include `<cstdio>`